# Update app from DMG: check versions

Tags: macos, bash

I download `DMG` with my app and update my app using it.

I'm using the following bash script for this:

```
set -e
/usr/bin/hdiutil attach "mydmg.dmg" -mountPoint "/Volumes/My update" -nobrowse
rm -rf "/Applications/My.app/Contents"
mkdir "/Applications/My.app/Contents"
cp -R "/Volumes/My update/My.app/Contents" "/Applications/My.app"
set +e
/sbin/umount "/Volumes/My update"
```

What I would like is to adjust this script to return a error in case the app's version inside of `DMG` is less than the one inside of the currently installed app.

This can be achieved by comparing two versions inside of `Info.plist` files (`CFBundleVersion` field) of the installed app and DMG's one.

Unfortunately, I'm a newbie in `macOS` and `bash`. I would like to get a code example on how to do this (if possible please :) ).

Just in case: `Info.plist` is a file which is located inside of the each macOS app bundle. It's located in the following folder: `My.app/Contents/Info.plist`.

Comment: Before scripting it, how would you do this manually? What files and the contents thereof, would you compare to determine if one version is newer than the other?  Please [edit] the original question with this information.

Comment: @Allan I've describe how to do it manually: it's required to compare `CFBundleVersion` values from `Info.plist` files of these two app bundles (installed app and the one in DMG).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not** a full solution, but here are some ideas:

Some plists are XML and some are binary.  `man plutil` will tell you how to convert a binary to XML.

What you probably want is this section in the XML version:

```
      <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
      <string>18615.1.26.11.23</string>
```

Can you figure out a way to find a line in a file and read the line after it?

```
cat /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Info.plist | while read VERSION; do
  if [ "$PREVIOUS" =~ ".*CFBundleVersion.*" ]
  then
    echo $VERSION; break
  fi
  PREVIOUS=$VERSION
done
```

When that loop exits, I expected $VERSION to be the full version number for Safari.  **But I tried it and it did not work.**

UPDATE: Per the suggestion by @nohillside, the entire loop I suggested can be replaced by

```
VERSION=$(defaults read /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Info.plist CFBundleVersion)
```

Also tested, and it **did** work.

Comment: Thanks for the `defaults read` command example. Now I need a code to compare two versions... Trying to figure out how to do it... :)

Comment: https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Conditional-Expressions.html